# App Service - Files in %TMP% location encrypted?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

If a file is uploaded to the %TMP% folder through my app services application, is it stored encrypted?

Information on this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/benchmark/azure/baselines/app-service-security-baseline) states that they are not: "Note that while locally attached disks can be used optionally by websites as temporary storage, (for example, D:\local and %TMP%), they are not encrypted at rest."

However, someone in this [thread](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/11299) states that the App Services file system is implemented on top of Azure Storage which does encrypt files at rest.

Let me provide some background in hope that some usable information will appear.
We need to have uploaded files encrypted. They must not appear plain on a HD. Our first idea was to upload a file to the Azure Blob Storage but there is a big number of read operations on the file, and that doesn't perform well enough when they are located on a blob storage.

Answer (score 0):

•   **`You can surely encrypt the files uploaded via the app service in the blob storage by using customer managed keys stored in the Azure key vault at rest also. For that purpose, you will have to create a storage account and ensure that encryption scheme was changed to customer managed keys wherein the customer managed keys are stored in the Azure key vault and are being assigned a user-assigned managed identity in the access policy created regarding all the key operations in the key vault. Once done, then import the application package as a ‘.zip’ test package through the SAS URL in the app service created and deploy it in the app service as a build solution. This will ensure that the deployment packages were imported to the App service and the build was created using the encrypted at REST package file using the SAS URI from the blob storage container`** as shown below: -

[image: Blob container files]
[image: Customer managed key encryption]
[image: Encryption at REST]
[image: Storage explorer]
[image: Web app deployment]
[image: App service deployment]

Thus, in this way, we can **be rest assured that data is encrypted even at REST when we are uploading the application data from the blob storage container that is encrypted at REST with the help of customer managed keys**.

For more information, please refer to the below link regarding the above: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-encrypt-at-rest-using-cmk***

Comment: Thanks for the effort but this doesn't answer the question. The first line states my requirement: "If a file is uploaded to the %TMP% folder through my app services application, is it stored encrypted?". I need files uploaded through my app service encrypted, for example, a user uploads a file using the upload form field. I don't need the application files encrypted. Also, I mentioned that after the upload, we do a large number of reading operations so I am asking about the %TMP% folder. We tried uploading to Azure Storage and reading from there but it is slow in our case.

Comment: Yes, they are encrypted at REST because since you are using customer managed keys option for storing your sensitive data in the Azure blob storage, these keys encrypt the data with modern encryption algorithm with the keys created in key vault with the user assigned managed identity having only specified access for it.